# can a c# program start with a '{'; if not, why not?

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-errors, specifications

My question, to which the answer is not known to me is stated in the title, i.e.:

**can a c# program start with a `{`; if not, why not?**

Everything that follows below details my research & thought process to date:

Note: referencing the "*c# Language Specification 5.0*";
code compiled with vs2015 community edition.

From §2.2.2 Lexical grammar, this sentence appears to imply that one can start with a `{` because a `{` is a token:

"Every source file in a C# program must conform to the input production of the lexical grammar (§2.3)."

§2.4 **Tokens** include *punctuators* and `{` is a punctator [§2.4.5 Operators and punctuators]

However, §9. Namespaces begins "C# programs are organized using **namespaces**."

§9.1 **Compilation units**:  "A **compilation-unit** defines the overall structure of a source file."

compilation-unit:

extern-alias-directives*opt* using-directives*opt* global-attributes*opt*

namespace-member-declarations*opt*

"*namespace-member-declarations* of each compilation unit of a program *contribute members* to a single declaration space called the *global namespace*"

This compiles:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

This does *not* compile:

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So, although `{` is a token, it does not contribute a member ... that is possibly why the compiler rejects the  beginning `{`.

However, the *namespace-member-declarations* are optional ~~ for that reason, *perhaps* the compiler should allow an intial `{`.

this is a *block*:

```
{
}
```

not every *block* must be a *something-block*, see the last example below.

§1.5 **Statements**

"A ***block*** permits multiple statements to be written in contexts where a single statement is allowed.
A block consists of a list of statements written between the delimiters `{` and `}`."

one more example which compiles clean using blocks for scoping:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            System.Int16 integer = System.Int16.MaxValue;
        }
        {
            System.Int32 integer = System.Int32.MaxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not asked any question in your question - only in the title.  And if you want to post a self answered question, you have to post the answer as an answer, not in the body of the question.

Comment: update the thread or delete it because right now, I don't see where you are heading with this. i'd really like to see where so plz update.

Comment: I'd file this under 'Not useful'

Comment: @JK i've edited the body of the question in response to your comment above; the title is my question; the body is my analysis to date; i'm stuck at this point, hence i've posted the above question.

Comment: @KevinAvignon the purpose of this question is because i wish to deepen my understanding of c#

Comment: @MitchWheat FWIW, for me it's very useful.  *chacun à son goût*

Comment: worrying about the position of a useless '{'  will not "wish to deepen my understanding of c# "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the namespace-member-declarations are optional ~~ for that reason, perhaps the compiler should allow an intial {.

No, that's not what it being optional means - it means "there doesn't have to be one", not "you can have anything you like instead".

Basically, a compilation unit consists of the directives you've mentioned, global attributes, and member declarations. That's all that can appear at the top level. A block is *not* a member declaration (or a global attribute, or a directive) and so can't appear at the top level.

Here's another hint:

> A block permits multiple statements to be written **in contexts where a single statement is allowed**.

A single statement isn't allow at the top level either. This isn't valid code:

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Nope, can't have a statement here.");
```

Again, it doesn't follow the grammar - it's not a member declaration.

Finally, even if blocks *were* allowed at the top level, they'd have to be changed for your code to be valid - because you're trying to declare a class within the block, which isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you, Jon; very much appreciated; for me, navigating through "*c# Language Specification 5.0*" is exciting, although my wish is that it had the overall *clarity* of your "*[c# in depth](https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-third-edition)*". `B-)`